Does Potent Spellcasting (Druid) work with Shillelagh?
I play a Druid Character. Does Potent Spellcasting from the Level 7 Feature Elemental Fury also add the wisdom modifier to the Shillelagh Cantrip?

Shillelagh
A Club or Quarterstaff you are holding is imbued with nature’s power. For the duration, you can use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using that weapon, and the weapon’s damage die becomes a d8. If the attack deals damage, it can be Force damage or the weapon’s normal damage type (your choice).
The spell ends early if you cast it again or if you let go of the weapon.
Cantrip Upgrade. The damage die changes when you reach levels 5 (d10), 11 (d12), and 17 (2d6).


Level 7: Elemental Fury
The might of the elements flows through you. You gain one of the following options of your choice.
Potent Spellcasting. Add your Wisdom modifier to the damage you deal with any Druid cantrip.
Primal Strike. [...]

Does that mean that an attack with a Quarterstaff after having cast Shillelagh and having the Potent Spellcasting feature, would (at Level 7) do 1d10 + 2 * Wis damage?

It is generally found that a Shillelagh is exceedingly effective when used alone :-) :-(

(For comparison, the 2014 version is just 1d8 + spellcasting_ability_mod damage with no benefit from upcasting, and no option to do force damage instead.  2014 druid doesn't have Potent Spellcasting, but some cleric subclasses do, with the same phrasing, so answers could apply for clerics who somehow know Shillelagh as a Cleric cantrip.  2014 Nature clerics get Divine Strike instead of Potent Spellcasting, though.)

Related: How does Potent Cantrip interact with spells that involve weapon attacks?

No, it doesn't

Potent Spellcasting. Add your Wisdom modifier to the damage you deal with any Druid cantrip.

So if the cantrip deals damage, you increase it by your Wisdom modifier, so far so good.
But Shillelagh says (emphasis added):

A Club or Quarterstaff you are holding is imbued with nature’s power. For the duration, you can use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using that weapon, and the weapon’s damage die becomes a d8. If the attack deals damage, it can be Force damage or the weapon’s normal damage type (your choice).

The cantrip does not trigger an attack (it's not Booming Blade or Greenflame Blade), it just changes the weapon itself for future use (this is extra apparent in it being of the Transmutation school, not an Evocation cantrip or the like). The weapon now has a new damage die, and potentially alternate damage types, but it's a consequence of the transmuted form of the weapon, not the cantrip itself dealing the damage, any more than the spell Magic Weapon deals the damage when your Fighter buddy hits someone with it.
It's not wildly unbalancing to allow it, but it does grant a meaningful power boost to certain builds if you do so. A level 20 Fighter, with Str 20, fighting sword-and-board style with a longsword would make four attacks, at +11 to hit (+6 PB + 5 Str) each of which would deal 1d8+5(Str) damage on a hit; if all four hit, average damage would be 38 (4.5+5 per hit). A 13 Fighter/7 Druid with Wis 20 fighting "stick-and-board" style (using a club converted to a shillelagh) would get three attacks, also at +11 to hit (+5 PB + 5 Wis), and (because cantrips advance with character level, not class level) they'd each do 2d6+10(2xWis) damage. If all three hit, average damage would be 51 (7+10 per hit).
That's approximately 34% more damage every round, at the cost of a single Bonus Action (that could often be used prior to combat beginning, since recasting every 30 seconds or so would ensure it would work for at least five rounds in each combat at zero cost), and no cost to AC, accuracy, etc. It doesn't even appear to limit your use of magic weapons; unlike Magic Weapon, Shillelagh works just fine on magic weapons, so a +3 Club will benefit the Druid/Fighter just as much (it changes the damage die, but not other modifiers) as a +3 Longsword benefits the pure Fighter.
Importantly, you should compare to the other options for that level 7 feature. If you took Primal Strike instead, you'd be increasing your per round damage by 4.5 (it adds a single d8 of damage once on each of your turns). The only benefit Primal Strike gives, that Potent Spellcasting doesn't, is that the former works in beast form, and gives extra damage on a critical. But that mostly matters only to Moon Druids (wild shape is more utility than combat for all others); all other Druids would pick Potent Spellcasting in a heartbeat, because it would give them similar damage boosts with Shillelagh and boost all their other cantrips to boot. If you're interpreting a class feature such that one option is strictly better for almost all builds, and by a wide margin for not particularly pathological builds, I'd suggest your interpretation is not the intent of the rule.

Yes, it does
The Potent Spellcasting feature is not limited to cantrips that use spell attacks like Poison Spray or Starry Wisp, it works with any Druid cantrip, and Shillelagh is a druid cantrip.
Even though you are using a melee weapon attack instead of a spell attack to deliver it, the damage you deal with your Shillelagh weapon is caused by the attack as described in the cantrip:

If the attack deals damage, it can be Force damage [...]

The weapon by itself has a lower damage die (d4 for the club, d6 for the quarterstaff unless you make the attack with two hands), and cannot deal force damage. When you attack with a club or quarterstaff while Shillelagh is on, the attack deals the spell's damage, not the weapon's normal damage.
This is not overpowered. Compare this to for example Poison Spray, which at level 7 would deal 2d12 poison damage at range - or 13 points of expected damage. Assuming you have a spellcasting modifier of +4 (after using your Ability Score Improvement at level 4 to boost it), Shillelagh deals d10+8, or 13.5 points. It is a better damage type as nearly no monster is resistant to force, but the Druid is primarily a spellcaster, not a melee fighter (at least in human form), so unless you have a specialized build around it, the need to go into melee acts to balance the somewhat better damage.
At even higher levels, Poison Spray's raw damage outpaces Shillelagh's. For example at level 17, poison spray deals 4d12 or 26 raw damage, Shillelagh deals 2d6+10 or 17 damage.

@Tarod - Thanks for editing to capitalize the names and apologies for me (too hastily) rejecting the edit, as I thought spell names are lowercased in the rules. Upon checking, I see that has changed in 2024, and they are now being capitalized. Wasn't meaning to be rude.

No problem at all, really! In fact, I've got a question for you :D Some people say Potent Spellcasting doesn't work with Shillelagh because it's not a damaging cantrip and it doesn't make damage by itself, but the damage comes from the weapon. I'm not sure if your answer was a "yes" only if you choose Force damage instead of the weapon's normal damage type, or if you think it works in all the cases.

@Tarod I think the answer is “Yes” even if you chose the increased bludgeoning damage, as the damage comes from the attack, and the enhanced damage is still the spells, even if it counts as weapon damage, else it would be lower. And I think there's no issues from by that either. The only fringe cases where you's chose bludgeoning over force are if a monster is vulnerable to it, or immune to force or maybe you have a feature that only works on bludgeoning.

Ok, understood. Thanks for answering! I'm of the opinion that Shillelagh shouldn't interact with Potent Spellcasting, but the debate is intense around the internet and without some guidance/updated SAC from WotC is difficult to defend my position :D

@Tarod Yes I can understand the other perspective for bludgeoning, it seems less clear-cut there. Maybe someone else will post an answer to argue for it, usually that's better than watering down a clear answer, and it allows people who like that view to upvote it.
